# How to plot comparison between two categorical (Nominal) series with pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, classification, dataframe

I am trying to compare two different classification of a serie of elements. Suppose I want to obtain a graphic like this:
[image: Comparison between two classification of N element (on y axis)]

Obtained with the following iPython session:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 446 entries, element0 to element445
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Classification1       446  non-null values
Classification2    446  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2)

In [2]: pylab.pcolor(df, cmap='Oranges')
Out[2]: <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection at 0x55dc650>

In [3]: pl.show()
```

1) How can I see if the same color is used for the same value in the two classification? Ie. how can I test if element1, which has the same color over the two classification, has also the same value (for example is classified as 1 both in Classification1 and in Classification2)?
I tried to use `pl.legend()` but it tells me:

```
In [54]: pl.legend()
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py:4486: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "
```

2) Is there a better way to compare graphically the two classifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more in line with what you want compared to your previous answer

```
levels = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
a = np.random.choice(levels, size=10)
a_array = np.vstack((a, a)).T

b = np.random.choice(levels, size=10)
b_array = np.vstack((b, b)).T

ax = plt.subplot(121)
CS = ax.contourf(a_array, 2, level=levels, colors=('r', 'g', 'b'))

ax = plt.subplot(122)
CS = ax.contourf(b_array, 2, level=levels, colors=('r', 'g', 'b'))

Cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)

Cbar.set_ticks(levels)
Cbar.set_ticklabels(["series 1", "series 2", "series 3"])
```

[image]

As far as I know `pcolor` is unable to set the labels in this way. Although if it could that qwould be a better way to do it

Comment: Interesting.. In fact, what I need, is compare line to line, side by side the two subplots, in order to view if the second classification is more interleaved than the first (assume that each line is a different element).. Anyway your use of two subplots is useful..

Comment: Then the colors are always represented by the same color in your example. Are the values for the class labels known e.g you have a list of all the possible classes and their numerical values?

Comment: I have changed my answer completely based on your comments, I think you want to label the colorbar by the classification. This is only achievable with `contourf` rather than `pcolor`, you can do a similar thing but the color bar is a continuous rather than distinct.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to use it.. For some reason mpl does not allow me to use `pcolor` on subplots, while `contourf` is allowed.. I am accepting this answer.. Any way to remove the ticks and preserving the labels on colorbar?

Comment: If you mean to remove the actual little tick in the colorbar then I'm unsure.